# How to identify the lack of a touch screen and keyboard on Windows Mobile 6.5

Tags: c#, windows-mobile

How to identify the lack of a touch screen and keyboard on Windows-mobile 6.5?

If I don't touch the screen or press any key I need to go back to the main screen

How I can do it on C# on Windows Mobile 6.5?

Comment: Are you asking about the presence of those devices or about an idle timeout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do this on my devices.

Just add a `Timer` and a short function called `Reset()`.

```
const int TIME_LIMIT = 50000; // set to whatever you need
int timeout;
Timer Timer1;

void Form1() {
   Timer1 = new Timer();
   Timer1.Interval = 200; // 200 milliseconds
   Timer1.Tick += new EventHandler(Timer_Tick);
}

void ShowSubPanel() {
  Timer_Reset();
  panelSub1.BringToFront();
}

void Timer_Reset() {
  Timer_Stop();
  Timer_Start();
}

void Timer_Start() {
  timeout = 0;
  Timer1.Start();
}

void Timer_Stop() {
  Timer1.Stop();
}

void Timer_Tick() {
  if (TIME_LIMIT < timeout++) {
    Timer_Stop();
    // Here, call your Main Form
    Main.BringToFront(); // I use Panels instead of forms
  }
}
```

Comment: Just as a bit of info, if you have many Forms (I realize you're using Panels instead) this would get a bit tedious and it would be really hard to extend/maintain.

Answer (score 2):

I'll agree with Henk's comment that it's not clear if you want to detect the lack of input from a user or detect whether those interfaces are present at all.  For detecting user idle conditions, [this might be of interest](http://blog.opennetcf.com/ctacke/2009/05/19/DetectingApplicationIdle.aspx).  For detecting hardware interface availability, [this might help](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/netcfteam/archive/2006/10/02/platform-detection-iii_3a00_-how-to-detect-a-touch-screen-on-windows-ce-in-.net-cf.aspx).